# Spring Reactor - Wait until a mono is finished then do next Mono

Tags: project-reactor, spring-webflux

Lets say I have a repository.save(..) method which returns a Mono.

Also lets say I have a repository.findByEmail(..) which returns a Mono.

**Problem:**

I want that the first Mono finishes AFTER do the second Mono.

```
repository.save(..).then(repository.findByEmail(..))
```

However, the second Mono here always gets executed first?
I was under the impression that `.then(..) finishes and then plays another Mono`

The source code says:
`Let this {@link Mono} complete then play another Mono.`

What is the solution to my problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What makes you think that this operator doesn't behave as expected?

The following example shows it does:

```
Mono.just("first").log()
                .then(Mono.just("second")).log()
                .subscribe();
```

Logs:

```
[main] INFO  reactor.Mono.IgnoreThen.2 - | onSubscribe([Fuseable] MonoIgnoreThen.ThenIgnoreMain)
[main] INFO  reactor.Mono.IgnoreThen.2 - | request(unbounded)
[main] INFO  reactor.Mono.Just.1 - | onSubscribe([Synchronous Fuseable] Operators.ScalarSubscription)
[main] INFO  reactor.Mono.Just.1 - | request(unbounded)
[main] INFO  reactor.Mono.Just.1 - | onNext(first)
[main] INFO  reactor.Mono.Just.1 - | onComplete()
[main] INFO  reactor.Mono.IgnoreThen.2 - | onNext(second)
[main] INFO  reactor.Mono.IgnoreThen.2 - | onComplete()
```

Please add `log` operators and share the logs in your question.

Comment: Hi Brian. Thanks for your effort and reply. I found the mistake already. It was on my side. You are totally right. The operator behaves as expected.

Comment: Glad you've found the issue - the adding multiple `log` operators can be useful in those times!